# Is Localizable.strings required for the root language of an app?

Tags: iphone, localization

As we're enabling our (English) application to be localized, we're replaced all in-line strings with NSLocalizedString() calls. Since all of our English strings are all there in-line with the code, e.g. NSLocalizedString(@"OK, @"OK button in a message box"), is there any reason we need the English version of Localizable.strings? When we try removing the strings from the English Localizable.strings, the program seems to work fine. Just wanted to double check if there was some side-effect to not having that around. Thanks, alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main points of using the `NSLocalizedString()` macro is so that your programming code can be parsed with the `genstrings` command-line tool to generate the corresponding `Localizable.strings` file(s) (see [Resource Programming Guide: About the String-Loading Macros](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH6-SW8) and [Using the Genstrings Tool to Create Strings Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH6-SW9)).

That `Localizable.strings` file then serves as a starting point for your translators, to use to translate to another language. Without that file to work with, your translators would basically need access to your source code in order to see all the strings you want to use (which kind of defeats the purpose).

Yes, your English version works fine right now, since if a localized version of the string you try to get in code –– for example, `NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"")` –– cannot be found in a `.strings` file, it simply uses the `@"OK"` string that you passed in.

Another reason why you should likely be keeping the English `Localizable.strings` is that you should generally try to avoid using high-ASCII characters in your code, but should use the full range of available characters in your actual user interface. For example, you may not want to put the following characters in your code, but would want to use them in your user interface:

… (horizontal ellipsis) (U+2026)
“ (left double quotation mark) (U+201C)
” (right double quotation mark) (U+201D)
‘ (left single quotation mark) (U+2018)
’ (right single quotation mark) (U+2019)

So in code, you'd do something like this:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"Add Bookmark...", @"")
```

and then in your `.strings` file (which is UTF16, so this is fine):

```
"Add Bookmark..." = "Add Bookmark…";
```

Comment: Right, the key question for us is whether there is any point to having the English Localizable.strings in the app bundle that gets shipped. Since the english strings are all in the code, it seems to be few unnecessary kilobytes. Admittedly, not a big deal, but was curious.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to use the words as keys, if you want to change that `Ok` for something else and you have any other `Localizable.strings`, you will have to edit every single of them to update the `Ok`key.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Is Localizable.strings supposed to be a de-duped version of what is in the source code? It doesn't appear to be on our side.

Answer (score 0):

Surely your translators will want your Localizable.strings file to work from. And want it to be **ALL** the strings.

(It is true that the system will fall back to the key, but relying on that seems like bad practice. And you'll find it more reliable to use proper punctuation in a Unicode file, which source code seldom is.)

Comment: Yeah, we'll need to give the localizers the english Localizable.strings. Just wondering whether it needs to be part of the bundle we give to Apple.

Comment: In theory it does not. In practice, all it takes is one non-ASCII character to mess you up. What are you going to save by not including it?